# How to remove a key from a clojure tree using specter?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, specter

I have been coming up to speed using the Clojure Specter library (https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter).  What I am having an issue with is removing a key using transform or setval.  I can set it to nil, but how do I remove a key?

Answer (score 6):

```
(setval :a NONE {:a 10 :b 20})
=> {:b 20}
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
(transform [ALL] #(when (not= (key %) :a) %) {:a 1 :b 2})
=> {:b 2}
```

Comment: Under Clojure 1.9.0, Specter 1.1.0, this gives me `ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry  clojure.core/key (core.clj:1559)`.

Comment: Same here, still getting a `ClassCastException` if you try the above.

Answer (score -2):

According to this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/3mr3rp/functionalnavigational_programming_in/), you cannot `dissoc` with specter (you can filter), but you can with [instar](https://github.com/boxed/instar).

EDIT: this is now possible.